# How to detect when a cookie is at capacity (via Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there a reliable way in Javascript to know when I am approaching (or when I have exceeded) the capacity of a cookie?

My best idea so far is to write the data to the cookie then read it back out and see if it matches...if not, I can assume the cookie is full (or disabled). Will that approach work on all major browsers, and/or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You should first be asking yourself the question why are you approaching the limit?  The maximum size is 4K, and weird things can happen when you get close to that limit (such as not being able to delete the cookie).  Can you use the cookie to store an identifier that points to a database record instead containing all this data you're trying to store in the cookie?

Comment: Regardless of the reason, it's still a valid question. I'm using the cookie as a temporary storage for a list of items. The list will be uploaded periodically to the server via JSON and then purged locally, but the server is slow so the list may grow lengthy. The cookie solution is a fallback for a LocalStorage version.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that it may be a valid question.  However if you truly are expecting to approach the limit of cookie sizes, prepare to deal with side effects, since that's not really the intended use of cookies.  If I were you I'd have your own specified limit, such as 3.8K or some arbitrary limit well under the browser-specific limits, which you enforce manually in your processing logic.

Comment: There are also solutions here which have alternatives to LocalStorage besides cookies: http://jensarps.de/2010/04/10/dont-use-cookies-use-localstorage/